# Updating controls with dynamic values, dynamodb or lambda+git

Tags: amazon-web-services, git, amazon-dynamodb

We have a set of control which enforce tagging standards through the estate.  These controls are easy if the values are "true" or "false".  In most cases they are unique to the account, such as "cost_code"

Currently, when a user vends an account, a team will update a json in git with the new tag value such as "cost_code", they will have to manually trigger a deployment to update the controls based on the updated json.

Rather than using a single json which we manually update, there could be a better option.

During the account vend process the user will be prompted for the "cost_code" value.  This is then storied in DynamoDB.  The controls are built from the values stored in DynamoDB.  From here we can trigger a git pipeline bases on changes made to dynamodb.

An alternative could be to use a a lambda to commit and push an MR to the json file from the values added at the account vend process.  The lambda validates, and commits the cost code id to the json, then commit then triggers a pipeline deployment pushing changes out in the controls.

Is DynamoDB a suitable solution?
Is there an alternative method i am missing?